# Multiple App on same apache server for asp.net core using other port

Tags: apache, ubuntu, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-3.1

I have deployed my one asp.net core app on apache server with default port 80
i wanted to deploy another asp.net core app on same apache server with other port.
is it possible...

checked [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-deploy-net-core-application-on-linux/) for reference.

Comment: share current configuration in question.

Comment: same configuration on given link

Comment: are you using the same asp.net server or same? are you using context name for application? i.e /test

Comment: i have basic configuration for any asp.net core with dbcontext and appsettiing.json database configuration

Comment: The question is tagged as "google-cloud-platform". Are you facing any issues with the Google Cloud Platform infrastructure?